# How to use formatters in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, formatter

I have such code in Python 2 :

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"
print formatter % (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

How do I rewrite for Python 3 so that it works?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not the formatter. In Python 3, `print` is a function.

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"
print (formatter % (1, 2, 3, 4))
```